# Geocoder Illegal argument

Tags: java, location

Trying to figure out the geocoder limitation. So far I have heard that maybe you can't parse below -90 and above 90 ranges for longitude and latitude. I get an illegalArugmentException latitude == -122.334707

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;

double longitude = Double.parseDouble(loc.getLongitude());
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(loc.getLatitude());
address = coder.getFromLocation(longitude, latitude, 1);

Address location = address.get(0);

loc.setCountry(location.getCountryName());
loc.setPostalOrZipcode(location.getPostalCode());
```

Comment: Considering that the earth is round (according to some people), where exactly would latitude `-122` point to? Or are you hoping that it would "wrap around" to the other side?

Comment: go to http://www.latlong.net/c/?lat=33.348487&long=-111.974422 and it works

Comment: Of course it works, because it's *longitude*. There's no *latitude* over 90 or below -90.

Comment: that solves my problem, thank you :) longitude and latitude is reversed.